# jQuery Animated sliding top fixed nav

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having some trouble getting some functionality to work.

I've got a header positioned absolute over a hero image. When the user scrolls down I'd like the nav to appear from the top and be in a fixed position (but slide in). Then when the user scrolls back up the nav will slide back up before the 'hero nav is revealed again'.

Basically like this website: http://www.invisionapp.com/

I've managed to get half of it to work (sliding down from the top) but only when the header has an initial top position of 0px. see: (http://jsfiddle.net/k2jyS/1/) - However, it doesn't slide back up either - just suddenly vanishes.

Here is the basic outline of my mark up

```
<header>
    This is a header
</header>
<div class="hero">
    <!-- hero image -->
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" />
</div>
<section class="content">
    LONG PAGE CONTENT
</section>
```

The CSS

```
header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.hero {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.hero img {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.fixed header {
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    top: -80px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e4e4e4;   
}
```

The jQuery so far

```
var nav = $('body');
var scrolled = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if (200 < $(window).scrollTop() && !scrolled) {
        nav.addClass('fixed');
        $('header').animate({top: 0},0);
        scrolled = true;
    }

   if (200 > $(window).scrollTop() && scrolled) {
        nav.removeClass('fixed');
        $('header').removeAttr('style');
        scrolled = false;      
    }
});
```

And here is the example fiddle which is where my nav appears 40px from the top:
http://jsfiddle.net/k2jyS/

(which is slide animating from the bottom because of the 40px top).

Any idea on how I can achieve the desired effect that I'm after? Thanks all!

**EDIT** - Here is the final working jQuery. I also had to remove the CSS transition from the header.

```
var nav = $('body');
var scrolled = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {
if (200 < $(window).scrollTop() && !scrolled) {
    nav.addClass('fixed'); 
    $('header').animate({top: 0}, 1000);
    scrolled = true;
  }

  if (200 > $(window).scrollTop() && scrolled) {
    $('header').animate({top: -80}, 200, function() {
        nav.removeClass('fixed');
        $('header').removeAttr('style');
    });
    scrolled = false;
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k2jyS/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that your biggest issue was that you hadn't actually animated the scrollout in your code. Still, when I tried it out, I found that for some reason removing your fixed class in the same if statement as your scrollout animation somehow screwed everything up. this works properly, though:

```
var nav = $('body');
var scrolled = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {

  if (100 < $(window).scrollTop() && !scrolled) {
    $("header").css({top: "-80px"}); 
  }

  if (150 < $(window).scrollTop() && !scrolled) {
    nav.addClass('fixed');   
  }

  if (200 < $(window).scrollTop() && !scrolled) {
    $('header').animate({top: 0});
    scrolled = true;
  }

  if (200 > $(window).scrollTop() && scrolled) {
    $('header').animate({top: -80});
    scrolled = false;
  }
  if (100 > $(window).scrollTop() && scrolled) {
    nav.removeClass('fixed');
    $('header').removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

I found that giving the animation a longer easing time made it more noticeable, at least for testing and making sure that it was actually animating.

EDIT: My revised code will work, but you could greatly simplify this if you removed this line from your `header` `CSS`: `transition: all 0.5s ease;` because `Javascript` is not waiting for your easing to finish before executing the next line, so things that could neatly happen one after the other under normal circumstances have to be called at different times from one another, which is why I've had to split this into so many separate if statements. Without that declaration, your code could look like this:

```
var nav = $('body');
var scrolled = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {
  if (200 < $(window).scrollTop() && !scrolled) {
    nav.addClass('fixed'); 
    $('header').animate({top: 0}, 1000);
    scrolled = true;
  }

  if (200 > $(window).scrollTop() && scrolled) {
    scrolled = false;
    $('header').animate({top: -80}, 1000, function(){          
      nav.removeClass('fixed');
      $('header').removeAttr('style');
    });
  }
});
```

the anonymous function within the `animate()` is a `complete()`, meaning it waits for the animation to finish before moving on. I was not able to apply that concept to your scroll in to collapse the if statements when you still had a `transition` declaration in your `CSS`.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply but it still doesn't have the desired effect. When it scrolls down the first time it doesn't come from the top. See: http://jsfiddle.net/k2jyS/2/

Comment: I edited the code above so it comes from the top now. I also explained why I think this was more complicated than it needed to be.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that having the CSS transition was causing problems! I used your edited code and then changed it slightly (added a function after the animation) and I finally got it working to my liking - couldn't have done it without you! For those interested here is the revised code (I'll edit it in at the top too): http://jsfiddle.net/k2jyS/3/

Comment: you're very welcome! dunno if you caught this, but I just re-tested and had to revise it so that the `scrolled = false'` was outside of the `complete()` because otherwise it was scrolling up forever.

Comment: I also believe that as the asker, you're allowed to accept this answer, which is functionally different from simply upvoting it.